# make @jsonignore use a setter over a isMethod?

Tags: json, jackson, fasterxml

This is my class

```
public class HouseJPAImpl implements House {

public RoomJPAImpl room;

public RoomJPAImpl getRoom(){
return this.room;
}

public void setRoom(RoomJPAImpl room){
this.room = room;
}

@Override
public boolean isRoom(){
return false;
}
}
```

My code gets confused with getRoom and isRoom.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Conflicting getter definitions for property "room": com.shared.model.restimpl.jpa.HouseJPAImpl#getRoom(0 params) vs com.shared.model.restimpl.jpa.HouseJPAImpl#isRoom(0 params)

I tried putting the @jsonignore on the isRoom method but then i dont get the room property in JSON.

Is there a way to use the getRoom over isRoom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this is something that Jackson 2.3 will handle gracefully (see https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/238).

But until it gets released, there are 2 main ways to handle this:

- Add `@JsonIgnore` on `isRoom()`, but keep `@JsonProperty` on `getRoom()`
- Change visibility settings to filter out all `isXxx()` methods: can either set global settings (`ObjectMapper` has something like `setVisibility`), or use annotation `@JsonAutoDetect` on classes

If this is an isolated case, you are probably better off by just using first one.